# Nginx.conf error when trying to docker-compose

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I got an vs solution, which contains multiple projects

[image: Project]

Nginx.conf created at ClientApp/Angular

[image]

My docker-compose file

```
clientapp:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}clientapp
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: src/ClientApp/Angular/Dockerfile
ports:
  - 4200:80
```

Clientapp Dockerfile

```
FROM node:19.5.0-alpine3.17 AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:1.19-alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/angular /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

When i'm trying to compose it up, I've got an error

> => ERROR [stage-1 4/4] COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

> failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::qfcrdm6j5llxkmhzbg2bhwu8c: "/nginx.conf": not found

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set the wrong build context for your `clientapp` service.

Currently it's `.` that means the project root directory *(where your `docker-compose.yml` file is located, not the `ClientApp/Angular` directory)*. As we can see there is no any `nginx.conf` file *(or provide us the full structure of your project root folder)*.

Try to specify context similar to `dockerfile:` path, something like this *(assuming that `src` is your project root directory)*:

```yaml
clientapp:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}clientapp
  build:
    context: ./ClientApp/Angular
    dockerfile: ./ClientApp/Angular/Dockerfile
  ports:
    - 4200:80
```

Or even simpler: If you use one Dockerfile *(with default name)*. You can specify just build directory:

```yaml
clientapp:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}clientapp
  build: ./ClientApp/Angular
  ports:
    - 4200:80
```